# How can I use a custom URL for an Admin Menu Item?

Tags: magento2, module, adminhtml

I made a custom admin menu item in Magento 2 and the menu item is pointing to the Magento2 Pages URL. I want the menu item to point to a custom module URL

Custom module URL is

> http://127.0.0.1/magento/demo/helloworld

Here is the link to all the files and folders of my Custom Module in Magento2

> https://github.com/sneurgaonkar/HelloWorld.git

Answer (score 2):

You need to add  menus at ***Acl resource***

So you need to create `acl.xml` at `HelloWorld/etc/` and at menu item at there.

**Acl code may:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Acl/etc/acl.xsd">
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <resource id="Magento_Backend::admin">
                <resource id="Magento_Backend::content">
                    <resource id="Magento_Backend::content_elements">
                        <resource id="Webmull_Helloworld::demo_menu_item" title="Demo Menu Item" sortOrder="20" />
                        <resource id="Webmull_Helloworld::demo_menu_item1" title="Demo Menu Item1" sortOrder="30"/>
                    </resource>
                </resource>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</config>
```

*After that you need to flush cache.*

Comment: Okay. I got it. But one more question is.. where do i have to provide the link to my module?

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

1. add the link to your controller in the menu (file /etc/adminhtml/menu.xml)
2. create your custom admin controller (class in VENDOR/MODULE/Controller/Adminhtml/...) something like:

   ```
   <?php

   namespace VENDOR\MODULE\Controller\Adminhtml\Test;

   use Magento\Backend\App\Action;

   class Redirect extends Action
   {
        public function execute()
        {
            $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
            $resultRedirect->setUrl($this->getImportUrl());
            return $resultRedirect; //<---- return is important
        }

        private function getImportUrl()
        {
           return 'https://www.google.com/';
        }
   }
   ```

Note: do not forget about return in controller